# counting categories in R

Tags: r

I have a file of about a million rows with categories. Some are the same, some are different. I want to know how much of each there are. What I do is this:

```
data<-read.table('Rtest2.txt', header=TRUE, sep='\t')
Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  EOF within quoted string

attach(data)
leaf_count=data[,1]

table(leaf_count)
```

The result however is only a fraction of all the different categories. It goes up to category 426 (of about 170,000) and that's it. Is there some limitation to R or am I doing something wrong?

Sam

Comment: Did you check to see what's causing the warning?

Comment: Based on the warning message, maybe your file wasn't completely loaded. After running read.table, try dim(data) to see if your data frame has the expected number of rows and columns. Also do str(data) to see if the data are structured as you expected. One more suggestion: "data" is an r function, so it's probably better to use a different name for your data frames.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data in a `data.frame`, *and you want to find out how many rows are duplicated*, I suggest using `aggregate` as in this example:

```
> d <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2), b=c("A","A","B","C"))
> d
  a b
1 1 A
2 1 A
3 1 B
4 2 C
> aggregate(1:nrow(d), by=d, FUN=length)
  a b x
1 1 A 2
2 1 B 1
3 2 C 1
```

To remove duplicates *in a single row*, use this:

```
> unique(d$a)
[1] 1 2

> unique(d$b)
[1] A B C
Levels: A B C
```

If only a few columns define a *category* (say, `a`and `b`), use this:

```
result <- aggregate(1:nrow(d), by=list(a=d$a, b=d$b), FUN=length)
```

Comment: I figured it out. The data was crooked at exactly the line where it stopped counting. Removing that data worked. Still I am curious about the aggregate approach. How would I implement such an approach with more than a million rows and 30,000 categories? Cause the way you showed me here above, it seems like a lot of manual work, which will not work with million rows/30,000 categories

Comment: @SamuelZwaan, it depends on what you really want to achieve. Running `x <- unique(data[,1])` is fast (less than a second) even with a few million rows. Using `aggregate` can't be much slower, unless you have hundreds of rows. Please, be more specific.

Comment: also, `table` should work just fine (as you originally suggested) *if* your data aren't messed up?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft, what I want to achieve is to see how many items there are in a specific category (the only thing is I have many many items and categories). I've got it to work in the meanwhile. I was just curious about your explanation on how to do it with aggregate. Don't quite see yet how to apply that on such a big data set. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @SamuelZwaan, a couple million rows is no big deal. Seriously. See edit above for using aggregate in a more general setting.